# Json-server depend on uuid instead of id

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, json-server

i use [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server)  and i use data like this:

```
{ 
 "posts": [
    { "id": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "id": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ]
}
```

i want use **uuid** instead of **id**, like this:

```
{ 
 "posts": [
    { "uuid": 1, "title": "json-server", "author": "typicode" }
  ],
  "comments": [
    { "uuid": 1, "body": "some comment", "postId": 1 }
  ]
}
```

but the problem is json-server use id as a **primary key** when you searching , for example:

```
endpoint/posts/1
```

- with **id** it 's work
- with **uuid** isn't work

Is there a solution  to make json-server depend on **uuid** instead of **id**

Comment: I'm not sure this can solve your problem, but you can set the id property with the `--id` or `-i` (alias) flag. (https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server#cli-usage)

Answer (score 2):

use   **--id resource_id** where resource is the name of the resource.  in your case:

```
json-server  db.json --id  'uuid'
```

Comment: Unknown option '--id'